# Get last 30 minutes from log file

Tags: linux, unix, tail

I have a log file that contain logs as follows

```
1486307866.155 240207 68.146.231.80 TCP_MISS/200 790 CONNECT clients1.google.com:443 - DIRECT/172.217.6.238 -
```

`1486307866.155` is the time in unix format with corresponds to `2017-02-05 07:17:46` (Format : Y-m-d H:i:s)

I need a unix command that give me the logs within last 30 minutes in the following format and discarding any details that i don't need.

`2017-02-05 07:17:46|68.146.231.80|clients1.google.com:443`

Comment: Even the unix timestamp will do as i can use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s','1486307866.155');` in php to convert to timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU date and GNU awk you can achieve what you want:

```
awk -v bt=$(date "+%s" -d "30 minutes ago") '$1 > bt {printf("%s|%s|%s\n", strftime("%F %T",$1), $3, $7)} ' yourfile
```

**Explanation:**

- the date command `date "+%s" -d "30 minutes ago"` gets the timestamp from 30 minutes ago
- the date command is replaced with its output via the command substitution feature `$( ... )`
- the awk option `-v` passes that timestamp as variable named `bt` into the awk script
- the script prints only those lines from the file having a value in column one (`$1`) larger than `bt` in your desired format

Comment: Thanks for the help...could you update the awk command to filter a domain e.g `*clients1.google.com*`. I would normally do `grep -E` for this but i think awk will do best here

Comment: @user2650277 : Why don't you try to do it yourself, and then post a new Q if you can't resolve it? See [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/awk.html) to get some basic ideas. Good luck

Comment: @user2650277 change the condition before the printf to `($1 > bt) && $7~/clients1.google.com/`

Comment: @LarsFischer Thanks a ton for the help...one last thing , what should i change in the command  to get only `/200` requests

Comment: I am very near it `awk -v bt=$(date "+%s" -d "30 minutes ago") '($1 > bt) && $7~/clients1.google.com/ {printf("%s|%s|%s|%s\n", strftime("%F %T",$1), $3, $4, $7)} ' your file` gives `2017-02-05 11:57:14|173.174.203.176|TCP_MISS/200|clients1.google.com:443`

Comment: @user2650277 just add another `&& $4~/\/200/` in front of the `{printf ... `